# DATE_FORMAT two times in Where Clause doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I want to check if a dataset is older than the current month -1 day (so if it's the first of November it should still be older than October). This is my SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM XY
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(calendar_day, '%Y-%m') <> DATE_FORMAT((CURRENT_DATE()-1, '%Y-%m');
```

But it doesn't work because of the second DATE_FORMAT. If I remove it, it works, but then it also compares the days and not the months. How do I solve this?

Comment: One `(` too many...

Comment: Wow sometimes you just can't think anymore. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to check if a dataset is older than the current month -1

Don't use `DATE_FORMAT()` on a column for this type of query.  Keep all date functions on the "current date".  Functions on columns impede optimization.

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM XY
WHERE calendar_day <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() - interval 1 day - interval 1 month);
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution for my problem! And also thanks for stating that I shouldn't use date_format

Answer (score 0):

Try this using year and month function:

```
SELECT *
FROM XY
WHERE (year(calendar_day) <> year(CURRENT_DATE()-1)) 
and (month(calendar_day)<>month(CURRENT_DATE()-1))
```